# CSS Dropdown menu hidden behind content IE7

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-7

I have a dropdown css menu that gets gets hidden behind the main page content when viewed in IE7. I've tried changing z-index values but have had no luck. I've also tried suggestions in other topics from this site but none have worked.

the page can be found here: [www.melbournedodgeball.com.au/dodgeball2012/about](http://www.melbournedodgeball.com.au/dodgeball2012/about)

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [CSS spec's paragraph on Z-index](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index) says that new stacking context is only created for positioned content with a z-index other than auto.

You have the `li` inside `#nav` with a `position:relative`, an apparently IE interprets this as a new stacking context.

**Try this:**

```
#nav li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;         // force IE to recognize stack at this point
}
```

Comment: I always forget this! It's the one thing about IE7 that makes it better than any modern browser.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
position:relative;
```

To your `<ul>`

Z-Index is specified relative to all other elements in the same stacking context. You can have a Z-Index of 100 but it wont make a bit of difference if the elements belong to completely different stacking contexts.

Answer (score 1):

I have test this code, It will work sure 
Please set this css for IE7 only

```
#menu {position:relative; z-index:100;}
```