# Dropdown nav bar hiding behind content in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have a dropdown nav bar and the when you hover over the items and the dropdown options appear in `IE7` they are hiding behind the slider.

I have tried `z-index` with no luck. Additionally, there is some spacing under the menu button and the first option in IE7 as well. I haven't tried to fix that as yet, my main concern is getting it to display above the slider content.

You can see it here: http://www.condorstudios.com/stuff/temp/index.php

Comment: The link is to a folder -- no index.

Comment: You sure? Works for me... index should be index.php

Comment: Try replicating your issue on jsfiddle.net. I don't have IE7, so I can't help you this way.

Comment: @Cthulhu If you have IE8 you can use developer tools to run the browser in the IE7 engine. Not sure what IE9 offers in this regard. I'll see if I can come up with something on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `$(document).ready()` handler:

```
var zi = 1000;
$('*').each( function() {
    $(this).css('zIndex', zi);
    zi -= 10;
});
```

In order to make sure this is only executed on IE7, add this **outside** your `<script>` tags, but in `<head>`:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var zi = 1000;
        $('*').each( function() {
            $(this).css('zIndex', zi);
             zi -= 10;
        });
    });
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of where to add it? I'm not a big JS person.

Comment: @Brett In line 30-31 in your index page (not sure what line that is in the original PHP sourcecode), you have: `<SCRIPT type=text/javascript> $(document).ready...`. Add that right after the opening brace.

Comment: Just looking; is there a cleaner way to do it than that. Looking now every element in my page seems to have an inline style applied to it for z-index and stuff in my footer ends up with z-indexes of `-930` etc

Comment: @Brett Not one that I know of. The problem is that IE7 seems to have an issue with recognizing element stacks, for some reason. Seems you'll have to do a "hack" anyway. Sorry.

Comment: Guess I'll just do my best to keep this hack to IE7 only so it doesn't get all messy for other browsers.

Comment: Can I separate this code from the other handler? I ask because then I can only call it for IE7. Like was there a reason why you said to put it inside that handler?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this same problem [recently here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618649/css-drop-down-menu-explosion-in-internet-explorer-7), so here are both fixes for IE7:

[CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581160/css-dropdown-menu-hidden-behind-content-ie7/):

```
/* show menu above content */
#nav li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;         // force IE to recognize stack at this point
}

/* normalize layout, IE7 not makes this automatically */
body,ul,li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Yep, I saw your post before I posted mine but couldn't get it to work. I also use a reset.css already and even tried using the margin/padding thing directly on the li class for them but it didn't work, so not sure why I'm getting the spacing. IE is fun :)